# Creating an event that triggers a second event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm trying to create a jQuery event that triggers a second event. The first event is clicking on the emoji id which refers to an image. The second is a mousemove event which moves the image around the page. The third event stops this event when the mouse click happens again anywhere in the body of the page and places the image at that absolute position. I was able to get the second and the third events to work but I can't get the first event to work with the second. Here is what I have so far for my jQuery:

```
var mouseTracker  = function(event) {
console.log(event.pageX, event.pageY, !!event.which)
$('#emoji').css('top', event.pageY);
$('#emoji').css('bottom', event.pageY);
$('#emoji').css('left', event.pageX);
$('#emoji').css('right', event.pageX);
}

var begin = function() {
$('body').on('mousemove', mouseTracker);
$('body').css('cursor', 'none');
}

var stop = function() {
$('body').off('mousemove', mouseTracker);
$('#emoji').css('postion', 'absolute')
$('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}

$('#emoji').on('click', begin);
$('body').on('click', stop);`
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the event from within the first event call.

```
$('#emoji').on('click', function() {
    begin();
    $('body').on('click', stop);
});
```

Comment: It cannot work, since the attached body handler is immediately triggered.

Comment: I may be wrong -- but why is it triggering if you're passing a function reference to the event object?

Comment: The event is propagated from `#emoji` to `body`. After exist from `#emoji` click handler the event is propagated to `stop()`, since it is already attached.

Answer (score 2):

During the click on `#emoji` the body click even is also triggered.
That leads to calling `stop()`. The propagation of that event to `body` can be blocked by `event.stopPropagation()` (or equivalent return `false` from `begin()`). The propagation should be manually stopped even if `body` on click handler is attached in `begin()`.

You may want one-time usage of some events. That can be done by binding using `.one()`. In that case the handler is detached after the first usage without manual `.off()`:

```
var begin = function (event) {        
    $('body').on('mousemove', mouseTracker);
    $('body').one('click', stop);
    $('body').css('cursor', 'none');
    return false; // event.stopPropagation();
}

var stop = function () {
    $('#emoji').one('click', begin);
    $('body').off('mousemove', mouseTracker);
    $('#emoji').css('postion', 'absolute')
    $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
}

$('#emoji').one('click', begin);
```